# Why same metric inside aws namespace aws/ecs and ECS/ContainerInsights shows significantly different data for CPU utilization?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-fargate

We are running a service cluster with 5 fargate nodes and have enabled container insights on ECS cluster. There is one container running per ecs task (each task is configured to use 2 vCPUs) and all of the cpu is dedicated to it.

```
Namespace - AWS/ECS
Metric name - CPUUtilization
ServiceName - service-1             
ClusterName - cluster-1             
Statistic - Maximum 
Period -  5 mins

This shows Maximum CPU utilization of 90%
```

But

```
Namespace - ECS/ContainerInsights
Metric name - CpuUtilized
ServiceName - service-1      
ClusterName - cluster-1      
Statistic - Maximum 
Period -  5 mins

Reserved
----------
Namespace - ECS/ContainerInsights
Metric name - CpuReserved
ServiceName - service-1      
ClusterName - cluster-1      
Statistic - Maximum 
Period -  5 mins

% Max utilization = Max utilized * 100 / Reserved

This shows Maximum CPU utilization = 50%
```

Both are calculated on same cluster and service and each fargate task is running only one container and all the resources allocated to task are dedicated to this one container, so then why both the metrics show different number ?